# Can't add swap in pop Os 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, partition, fstab, swap, uuid

I have recently installed **Pop OS 22.04** on my dell laptop. At the installation time I have chosen **/dev/sda2** partition for my swap partition. But the installer gone mad and used **/dev/sda2** and **/dev/sda8**, made them **cryptswap** and now using both partition (total 9 GB) as swap, naming them as **cryptswap**.

**I wants to use only one partition /dev/sda2 as swap.** But when I tries to do so, there is a problem: The both partitions are now named differently and their **UUID** is also different. When I use **blkid** command to see their UUID, it shows **19196f92-b927-4f9d-b6f4-6ec7ec5c08a4** and **344c6023-0d5a-4409-b22d-4f4065d969d4** respectly for both partitions **/dev/sda2** and **/dev/sda8**.

But again the thing is that the two files **cryptswap** and **cryptswap_D42wY** in the **/dev/mapper** directory are linked to these partition and using them and also assigning them the different **UUID** as **c6ad253a-34bb-4699-8956-ac18e9aa8b69** and **b30baf24-4c09-4068-a468-96831329ac92** respectively for both files.

So, how can I **remove or delink** these two files **cryptswap** and **cryptswap_D42wY** and **use only one partition /dev/sda2 as swap?**

I have already edited **/etc/fstab** file, but it doesn't work. For more detail I am putting the output of `sudo blkid` command.

```
sudo blkid

/dev/sda3: LABEL="popOs" UUID="b9f6da73-5573-4a59-ab5e-3396d0e1be3e" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a7586813-5de8-47ce-8dab-ea6c72bbe569"
/dev/mapper/cryptswap_D42wY: LABEL="cryptswap_D42wY" UUID="b30baf24-4c09-4068-a468-96831329ac92" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/cryptswap: LABEL="cryptswap" UUID="c6ad253a-34bb-4699-8956-ac18e9aa8b69" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Zorin" UUID="bf78eb24-f758-4de1-8634-96cb7d86a0f0" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="22df4dee-bfa5-f041-99b8-5255d849f7ca"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="popSwap" UUID="19196f92-b927-4f9d-b6f4-6ec7ec5c08a4" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="6db35de5-903b-4d4c-9643-8bc4ce0e760e"
/dev/sda7: UUID="532cc31c-e30c-4967-8b05-35dc129673a0" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTLABEL="Millennium Bug" PARTUUID="0f8b4a00-d430-492f-9198-56f8c7fa5624"
/dev/sda5: UUID="2e5a4299-343d-402b-85f4-59675538c1c9" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTLABEL="D-drive" PARTUUID="65ee92a3-b532-464c-a2a5-82277d350bc2"
/dev/sda1: UUID="CE68-C9E7" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="d79b75ff-e7c8-4206-9ea9-5aef66915f30"
/dev/sda8: LABEL="zorinSwap" UUID="344c6023-0d5a-4409-b22d-4f4065d969d4" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="e02be3ee-385f-49b4-8c64-8944ac421415"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="H" UUID="00b0cc40-a9f5-4ecf-82af-2f8edb588157" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="H-drive" PARTUUID="f09d5ff7-0f69-4be7-a8cd-eb9670ca3a3e"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem. The different UUID problem was because the `initramfs cryptroot hook` is trying to translate `cryptswap` into block device when I have `cryptswap` in **/etc/crypttab** file. The **blkid** command shows UUID for both the block device and **cryptswap** files.

The solution is below:

1. Comment the `cryptswap` related lines in the files **/etc/fstab** and **/etc/crypttab** using `nano`.
2. Execute `sudo swapoff -a` and `sudo update-initramfs -u`.
3. Reboot.

In the last I added swap partition which I wanted to use in the **/etc/fstab** file as below:

```
# Adding swap partition on /dev/sda2
UUID=19196f92-b927-4f9d-b6f4-6ec7ec5c08a4 none   swap    sw      0       0
```